# Conditional confirm message for Telerik GridButtonColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am new to these technologies.

I have a `radgrid` listing data sets and the reports associated with each data set. Users can click the delete icon in the `GridButtonColumn` to delete the report from the database.

If the user deletes the last report associated with the data set, I also want to delete the data set. But i want to throw a different confirmation message if this is the case.

Logic:
Click Delete > query database > if this is the last report associated with data set, throw message A, else throw message B

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="Delete"
 ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/Icons/delete.png" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
 ConfirmTitle="Delete" ConfirmDialogType="Classic"  
 ConfirmText="Are you sure want to delete the selected report?" />
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
    protected void RadGridUser_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.DeleteCommandName)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        int reportID = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["reportID"].Text);
        int datasetID = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["datasetID"].Text);

        string countQry = "select * from reportTable where datasetID=" + datasetID;
        DataSet dsCount = DBUtils.ExecuteDataset(countQry);

        //delete data if this is the only report left for the data set
        if (dsCount.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 1)
        {  //set ConfirmText = "Deleting this report will also delete the data set. Do you want to delete the data set?"
           //DELETE DATA
        }
        //set ConfirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete the selected report?"
        //DELETE REPORT
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to query the database and change the ConfirmText based on the query results with this GridButonColumn?

Comment: This post on Telerik forum should lead you to the solution http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamically-set-confirmtext-on-gridbuttoncolumn

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the thread offered by FeliceM which I believe is the answer (http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamically-set-confirmtext-on-gridbuttoncolumn), you can use a custom confirm as described here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-using-radconfirm-in-server-code.html.

The built-in confirmation fires before the server event, so you need to make sure you have the proper message when the page loads on the client, otherwise, if you need the confirnmation to come from the server, use the approach I linked.